# Stopping Browser Event Bubbling from a custom "Header" class to its GWT DataGrid/ListHandler

Tags: dom, gwt, datagrid, mouseevent

I'm creating a custom implementation of the GWT **Header<String>** class for use on a DataGrid **Column** that also uses a **ListHandler** to sort the data in this column.  I'm attempting to handle and cancel Browser events in the **Header** class such that if a user clicks on a particular <INPUT> **Element** rendered by this custom **Header** object,  we prevent the "mousedown" Event from bubbling back up to the DataGrid's event handler(as this incorrectly triggers the **ListHandler**'s column sorting methods, preventing the user from entering data into the <INPUT> **Element** in question).

I'm able to successfully isolate the events whose bubble up we want to "cancel" by implementing a **NativePreviewHandler** in my **Header** class with the following code:

```
        @Override
        public void onPreviewNativeEvent(NativePreviewEvent event) {
            final NativeEvent natEvent = event.getNativeEvent();
            final Element element = natEvent.getEventTarget().cast();
            final String eventType = natEvent.getType();                 
            if ("mousedown".equals(eventType)) {
                if (element.getTagName().equals("INPUT")) {
                    natEvent.preventDefault();
                    natEvent.stopPropagation();
                    event.cancel();
                }
            }
            return;
        }
```

Unfortunately no combination of the *preventDefault()*, *stopPropagation()*, or *event.cancel()* methods successfully stop the mousedown event from bubbling up to the parent **DataGrid**'s handlers.  When I attempted to debug this issue, I was able to confirm that although **DOM**.*previewEvent* method successfully called the **DOM**.*eventCancelBubble* and **DOM**.*eventPreventDefault*, the **DOM**.*dispatchEvent* method was still fired and ultimately triggered the **DataGrid**.*fireEvent* and a **ColumnSortEvent**.

Any guidance/approaches to prevent the GWT DataGrid from resorting itself if a particular portion of a custom Header is clicked would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can prevent the sorting of columns on `Header` click, with the following code snippet, by overriding onBrowserEvent2 API of `DataGrid`.

```
@Override
protected void onBrowserEvent2( Event event )
{
    EventTarget eventTarget = event.getEventTarget();
    if ( !Element.is( eventTarget ) )
    {
        return;
    }
    final Element target = eventTarget.cast();
    String id = target.getId();
    if ( id != null && id.equals( COLUMN_HEADER_ID ) )
    {
        return;
    }
    super.onBrowserEvent2( event );
}
```

Comment: if ( id != null && id.equals( COLUMN_HEADER_ID ) )
    {
        return;
    } is sufficient I believe